# Test using rails console user registration and create a record in another model which depends of user registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to test just the backend of RoR without the frontend. So using rails console, I want to register as a user and create a record in the student table. I am using devise gem for authentication. How can I test this flow? Thanks

Comment: Use a model test/spec?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the User by running `User.create(your_attributes_here)` where `your_attributes_here` are the required attributes needed (e.g. email address, password, password_confirmation, and so on.)
2. You could then run `user = User.first` (this finds the first User record) followed by `Student.create(your_attributes_here)` using `user` to associate the previously created User with the new Student record. This would look like `Student.create(user: user)`. Alternatively, you could add it as a callback in the User record. More information on Active Record callbacks can be found on the [Ruby on Rails Guides website](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).